# About the ring $\mathbb{Z[\sqrt{4}]}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I recently learned about quadratic ring extensions and among the various examples we were given $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{4}]$.

I am a bit puzzled by this object. I understand that it is not an Integral Domain since it has zero divisors and so a lot of nice properties are lost, but I can't seem to "fit" it anywhere among the other $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}]$ (where $d$ is not a square in $\mathbb{Z})$.

Is there some context in which the ring $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{4}]$ arises naturally?

Comment: $4$ is a square in $\mathbb{Z}$ so $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{4}]$ is just $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: $\Bbb Z$ adjoin 2?

Comment: $\Bbb Z[X]/(X^2-4)$?

Comment: We wait for your answer, Hektor.

Comment: @EthanAlwaise I don't understand what do you mean by "$\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{4}]$ is just $\mathbb{Z}$", the two rings $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{4}]$ and $\mathbb{Z}$ are not isomorphic as the former contains zero divisors

Comment: @Hektor One interpretation of $R[\alpha]$ for some $\alpha\in S\supseteq R$ is "the smallest subring of $S$ containing $R$ and $\alpha$."  By that definition, $\mathbb Z[2]$ and $\mathbb Z[-2]$ are both $\mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As suggested in comments, this notation is fatally ambiguous. That is, if it means "adjoin a square root of 4 to $\mathbb Z$", then we "adjoin" $2$ or $-2$, and, either way, have ... depending upon interpretation... done nothing, since there was already a $2$ and/or a $-2$ in $\mathbb Z$.

If, as comments suggest, it was meant to consider a sense in the general pattern of $\mathbb Z[x]/(x^2-4)$, then EDIT: as @rschwieb pointed out, the ideals $(x-2)$ and $(x+2)$ in $\mathbb Z[x]$ are not coprime... but let's pretend it's $\mathbb Q[x]$... (via Sun-Ze's theorem, a.k.a. "Chinese Remainder Theorem") we get $\mathbb Q[x]/(x-2)\oplus \mathbb Q[x]/(x+2)$, which is isomorphic to $\mathbb Q\oplus \mathbb Q$. With zero divisors, yes, etc. With $\mathbb Z[x]$, it's messier...

Comment: No, this is incorrect!  You can verify that the quotient ring only has trivial idempotents, and does not split. The problem is that the Chinese remAinder theorem does not apply to this pair of ideals: they are not coprime.

Comment: It is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z\times \mathbb Z$ as an abelian group, but not as a ring, though. It is at best a Noetherian, connected, reduced ring.

Comment: @rschwieb, Ah, true, I was thinking of $\mathbb Q[x]$, ...